Run Solr in the background on windows
I am on Windows Server and using Solr. I use bin/solr start -p 8984 as per this doc here https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/running-solr.html which starts the solr correctly. However, as soon as I close the command prompt windows the Solr also stops.
How can I start solr that keeps running in case I close the command prompt window, as well as once I log out to the server.
I tried starting solr as per their documentation that talks about running solr in the background but it isnt. It should be kept running even if cmd windows is closed or user is logged out.

Use nssm (non sucking service manager) and set it up as a windows service.
